# photo upload working on local host but not on server?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

hi i have a photo upload script which is working fine on my local host but when i upload it to my ftp server it doesn't upload the file. any ideas why this is, i get no error or anything just doesn't upload the file.

heres my index.php file:

```
 <div id="areas">

                <input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile" data-post="upload_image_1.php"  data-width="90" data-height="90" data-crop="true"/>


                <form id="sampleform" action="post_image_1.php" method="post">

                </form>
                <script>
                    $('#sampleform').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:$(this).attr('action'),
                            type:'post',
                            data:$(this).serialize(),
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(r){
                                $('#form-result').append(
                                '<div><b>Title: </b>'+r.title+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Description: </b>'+r.description+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Image/File: </b>'
                                  +'<a href="'+ r.url +'" target="_blank">'+ r.url +'</a>'
                                  +'</div>'
                                );
                            }
                        });
                });
                </script>
            </div>

            <script>
            // Calling jQuery "droparea" plugin
            $('.droparea').droparea({
                'init' : function(result){
                    //console.log('custom init',result);
                },
                'start' : function(area){
                    area.find('.error').remove(); 
                },
                'error' : function(result, input, area){
                    $('<div class="error">').html(result.error).prependTo(area); 
                    return 0;
                    //console.log('custom error',result.error);
                },
                'complete' : function(result, file, input, area){
                    if((/image/i).test(file.type)){
                        area.find('img').remove();
                        //area.data('value',result.filename);
                        area.append($('<img>',{'src': result.path + result.filename + '?' + Math.random()}));
                    } 
                    //console.log('custom complete',result);
                }
            });
            </script>

            <!-- /development area -->
        </div>
```

here's my post.php file:

```
<?php

// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('post-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


$data = $_POST['thumbnail'];
unset($_POST['thumbnail']);

if($data){

    // Uploading folder
    $folder = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);
    // If specifics folder 
    $folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);


    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_POST['pic1']) . '.mp4';

            $filename = addslashes($filename);

$sql=mysql_query('INSERT INTO ptb_photos SET file_name ="$filename",id="$_SESSION[user_id]", user_id="$_SESSION[user_id]"');


    $data = split(',', $data);
    file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($data[1]));

}
die(json_encode(array_merge(array('url' => $filename), $_POST)));

?>
```

And lastly heres my upload.php file:

```
<?php
session_start()
?>
<?

// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('upload-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


// Maximum file size
$maxsize = 10; //Mb
// File size control
if ($_FILES['xfile']['size'] > ($maxsize * 1048576)) {
    $r->error = "Max file size: $maxsize Kb";
}


// Uploading folder
$folder = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// If specifics folder 
$folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// PASS USER_ID HERE
$folder2 = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
if (!is_dir($folder2))
    mkdir($folder2);

// New directory with 'files/USER_SESSION_ID/'
$folder = $newDir . $folder2;


// If the file is an image
if (preg_match('/image/i', $_FILES['xfile']['type'])) {

    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . 'thumb_pic1.jpg';



} else {

    $tld = split(',', $_FILES['xfile']['name']);
    $tld = $tld[count($tld) - 1];
    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_FILES['xfile']['name']) . $tld;
}


// Supporting image file types
$types = Array('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg');
// File type control
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) {
    // Create an unique file name    
    // Uploaded file source
    $source = file_get_contents($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    // Image resize
    imageresize($source, $filename, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['crop'], $_POST['quality']);
} else
// If the file is not an image
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"], $filename);



// File path
$path = str_replace('upload_image_1.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

// Result data
$r->filename = $filename;
$r->path = $path;
$r->img = '<img src="' . $path . $filename . '" alt="image" />';

// Return to JSON
echo json_encode($r);

// Image resize function with php + gd2 lib
function imageresize($source, $destination, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false, $quality = 80) {
    $quality = $quality ? $quality : 80;
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($source);
    if ($image) {
        // Get dimensions
        $w = imagesx($image);
        $h = imagesy($image);
        if (($width && $w > $width) || ($height && $h > $height)) {
            $ratio = $w / $h;
            if (($ratio >= 1 || $height == 0) && $width && !$crop) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } elseif ($crop && $ratio <= ($width / $height)) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } else {
                $new_width = $height * $ratio;
                $new_height = $height;
            }
        } else {
            $new_width = $w;
            $new_height = $h;
        }
        $x_mid = $new_width * .5;  //horizontal middle
        $y_mid = $new_height * .5; //vertical middle
        // Resample
        error_log('height: ' . $new_height . ' - width: ' . $new_width);
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));
        imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
        // Crop
        if ($crop) {
            $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($width ? $width : $new_width, $height ? $height : $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($crop, $new, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($width * .5)), 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            //($y_mid - ($height * .5))
        }
        // Output
        // Enable interlancing [for progressive JPEG]
        imageinterlace($crop ? $crop : $new, true);

        $dext = strtolower(pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($dext == '') {
            $dext = $ext;
            $destination .= '.' . $ext;
        }
        switch ($dext) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
                imagejpeg($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $quality);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $pngQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
                $pngQuality = round(abs($pngQuality));
                imagepng($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $pngQuality);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                imagegif($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination);
                break;
        }
        @imagedestroy($image);
        @imagedestroy($new);
        @imagedestroy($crop);




    }
}


?>
<?php 
if($_FILES['xfile']['name'])
{
  $target_dir = '../'. '../'. 'data/'. 'photos/'. $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';

  $upload_file_name = basename( $_FILES['xfile']['name']);
  $upload_file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['xfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $target_file = $target_dir . 'pic1.jpg';
  $target_file_sql = $target_dir . mysql_real_escape_string($upload_file_name . '.');


  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['xfile']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) 
  {  

    if (copy($target_file, $target_thumb))
    {

    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>`. Also, why is your `<input>` outside of your `<form>` ?

Comment: also check that you have write privilege for the directory you are uploading to

Answer (score 1):

Did you CHMOD? So not CHMOD the folder to 777

Comment: What for FTP Client do you use ?